# How to extract/crop an OSM file to include entries that intersect with a GTiff?

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, geotiff-tiff, clip

I am trying to get just the datapoints that intersect with the boundaries of a GeoTiff image for some internal testing on an algorithm.

Are there any tools that can perform this operation?

If not, how would I script this behavior?

I would also like to preserve as much as data as possible from the original OSM file such as tags and other attributes.

I seek a solution that uses GDAL.

Here are the steps I need to perform:

1. Get the bounding box of the GeoTiff
2. Find all entries that intersect with those boundaries
3. Save those entries to a new OSM file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found an easy way to do this for anyone interested.

1. Get the bounding box of the Geotif using the command line utility gdalinfo
2. Use osmconvert -b"bottom_left_lat","bottom_left_long","top_left_lat","top_left_long" to extract the geotiff

   3. Enjoy your cropped OSM file!